# CUDA memory troubles

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I have a CUDA kernel which I'm compiling to a cubin file without any special flags:

```
nvcc text.cu -cubin
```

It compiles, though with this message:

> Advisory: Cannot tell what pointer points to, assuming global memory space

and a reference to a line in some temporary cpp file. I can get this to work by commenting out some seemingly arbitrary code which makes no sense to me.

The kernel is as follows:

```
__global__ void string_search(char** texts, int* lengths, char* symbol, int* matches, int symbolLength)
{
    int localMatches = 0;
    int blockId = blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x;
    int threadId = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y * blockDim.x;
    int blockThreads = blockDim.x * blockDim.y;

    __shared__ int localMatchCounts[32];

    bool breaking = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < (lengths[blockId] - (symbolLength - 1)); i += blockThreads)
    {
        if(texts[blockId][i] == symbol[0])
        {
            for(int j = 1; j < symbolLength; j++)
            {
                if(texts[blockId][i + j] != symbol[j])
                {
                    breaking = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (breaking) continue;
            localMatches++;
        }
    }

    localMatchCounts[threadId] = localMatches;

    __syncthreads();

    if(threadId == 0)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            sum += localMatchCounts[i];
        }
        matches[blockId] = sum;
    }
}
```

If I replace the line

```
localMatchCounts[threadId] = localMatches;
```

after the first for loop with this line

```
localMatchCounts[threadId] = 5;
```

it compiles with no notices. This can also be achieved by commenting out seemingly random parts of the loop above the line. I have also tried replacing the local memory array with a normal array to no effect. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

The system is Vista 64bit, for what its worth.

Edit: I fixed the code so it actually works, though it still produces the compiler notice. It does not seem as though the warning is a problem, at least with regards to correctness (it might affect performance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays of pointers like char** are problematic in kernels, since the kernels have no access to the host's memory. 
It is better to allocate a single **continuous** buffer and to divide it in a manner that enables parallel access.
In this case I'd define a 1D array which contains all the strings positioned one after another and another 1D array, sized 2*numberOfStrings which contains the offset of each string within the first array and it's length:

For example - preparation for kernel:

```
char* buffer = st[0] + st[1] + st[2] + ....;
int* metadata = new int[numberOfStrings * 2];
int lastpos = 0;
for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 2* numberOfStrings; cnt+=2)
{
    metadata[cnt] = lastpos;
    lastpos += length(st[cnt]);
    metadata[cnt] = length(st[cnt]);
}
```

In kernel:

```
currentIndex = threadId + blockId * numberOfBlocks;
char* currentString = buffer + metadata[2 * currentIndex];
int currentStringLength = metadata[2 * currentIndex + 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be associated with the char** parameter. Turning this into a char* solved the warning, so I suspect that cuda might have problems with this form of data. Perhaps cuda prefers that one uses the specific cuda 2D arrays in this case.